# Is there any way to disable input elements in typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to disable an HTML input element based on condition in TS file. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just use `disabled` attribute on the `input`..!

Comment: @RohitSharma I want to do it based on condition in typescpt file so

Comment: use `[disabled]="condition"` and switch `condition` in class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, you can just add the `[disabled]` property to the input, like this:

```html
<input [disabled]="inputDisabled" [(ngModel)]="myInput">
```

In the above example, `inputDisabled` would be a boolean variable on the component, perhaps like this:

```js
// app.component.ts

export class AppComponent {
  inputDisabled: boolean = false;
}
```

OR, if the boolean is passed via an input:

```js
// app.component.ts

export class AppComponent {
  @Input() inputDisabled: boolean;
}
```